# Sorting a collection by an attribute of an object inside it

Tags: collection, sorting, object

I am trying to sort a collection of objects by an attribute of an object inside each object (terminology there may not be correct(!)).

I have a collection of topic objects from the Simple Forum Magento module by WebIdeaOnline. The objects look like this:

```
Simple_Forum_Model_Topic Object
(
    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
    [_eventObject:protected] => object
    [_resourceName:protected] => forum/topic
    [_resource:protected] =>
    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => forum/topic_collection
    ...
    [_data:protected] => Array
        (
            [topic_id] => 7
            [parent_id] => 1
            [system_user_id] => 0
            [is_category] => 1
            [user_name] => admin
            [user_nick] =>
            [created_time] => 2014-05-16 10:05:57
            [update_time] => 2014-05-30 08:54:56
            [title] => General Forum
            [description] =>
            [url_text] => forum/general
            [url_text_short] => general
            [status] => 1
            [meta_description] =>
            [meta_keywords] =>
            [priority] => 110
            [total_posts] => 7
            [latest_topic] => Simple_Forum_Model_Topic Object
                (
                    [_eventPrefix:protected] => core_abstract
                    [_eventObject:protected] => object
                    [_resourceName:protected] => forum/topic
                    [_resource:protected] =>
                    [_resourceCollectionName:protected] => forum/topic_collection
                    [_cacheTag:protected] =>
                    [_dataSaveAllowed:protected] => 1
                    [_isObjectNew:protected] =>
                    [_data:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [topic_id] => 10
                            [parent_id] => 7
                            [system_user_id] => 7
                            [is_category] => 0
                            [user_name] => Joe Bloggs
                            [user_nick] => Joe
                            [created_time] => 2014-05-16 10:14:51
                            [update_time] =>
                            [title] => This is a topic for the General Forum
                            [description] =>
                            [url_text] => forum/general-forum-topic
                            [url_text_short] => general-forum-topic
                            [status] => 1
                            [meta_description] =>
                            [meta_keywords] =>
                            [priority] => 0
                        )
                        ....
                ....
        )
)
```

I want to sort the collection of these objects by the attribute `created_time` (value in example `2014-05-16 10:14:51`) in the `latest_topic` object which is inside the main topic object, as you can see in the structure above. Is this possible by altering the function below, which currently sorts the collection by `priority`, one of the top-level attributes, using `->setOrder`. Does anyone have any ideas for this?

```
public function initCollection()
{
    $this->_current_object = Mage::registry('current_object');
    $isModerator       = Mage::helper('forum/topic')->isModerator();
    $this->_objectsCollection  =  Mage::getModel('forum/topic')->getCollection();
        $this->_objectsCollection->setPageSize($this->_getLimit());
        $this->_objectsCollection->setOrder('priority', 'ASC');
        $this->_objectsCollection->setCurPage($this->_getCurPage());
        $this->_objectsCollection->getSelect()->where('parent_id=?', $this->_current_object->getId());
        $this->setAdditionalData();
    }
    return $this->_objectsCollection;
}
```

I am using Magento CE 1.7 and using the Simple Forum Magento module, although hopefully the sorting question is generic enough to apply to Magento collections in general!

Thanks so much for any help anyone can give. We have been struggling with this for weeks!

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
->addFieldToSort('priority','ASC')
```

instead of

```
->setOrder('priority', 'ASC');
```

Comment: why does not setOrder work..??

Comment: is addFieldToSort() working or not

Comment: The `->setOrder('priority', 'ASC');` is working, that is not the problem. Currently the collection is sorted by priority fine. Sorry if I didn't explain very well but my question was that I wanted to sort by the `created_time` of the `latest_topic` within each of the main collection objects.